# Call a MVC action to download the CSV by using console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, console-application

I am seeking for help. I have one MVC action without View, the function of this action is to download a CSV file. I want to use console application to call the action in order to download the file.

My controller:

```
Public void DownloadCSV()
{
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  sw.WriteLine("1,2,3,4");
  string remark = "Cool"; // -- Edited
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Download-"+remark+".csv"); // -- edited
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        Response.Write(sw);
        Response.End();
}
```

My Console Application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string result = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:2114/File/DownloadCSV");
        }

    }
}
```

This web application requires login. Is this why I cannot access to this url?

Comment: What happens when you run your console app?

Comment: @mjwills I tried to run it but nothing happens

Comment: I'm unable to find where you are calling to DownloadCSV() method from console application. Have you checked whether its calling or not ?

Comment: Define `nothing happens`. Do you mean `result` is a blank string? Something else?

Comment: If you use Postman, and do a GET against http://localhost:2114/File/DownloadCSV what does it show as the result there? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: Sorry. The result is my login page. So is there any method I can skip the login or probably insert the login from the console?

Comment: You might need to add the attribute `[AllowAnonymous]` to the function in Mvc. Obviously as drawback to this, its accessible by anyone.

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Valeklosse. I can now get the string result that I want, but the file is not downloaded.

Comment: Where do you expect the file to download **to**? What is the value of `result `?

Comment: I want to download the file to a shared folder names "Report". The full path is "C:\Report". The value of result now is "1,2,3,4\r\n"

Comment: in that case you need to save the string to a file. You can easily google how to do that in C#.

Comment: Can I download the file instead of the string. This is just basic, in future file name might be added DateTime.Now.ToString. Thus I cannot use client.DownloadFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string result = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:2114/File/DownloadCSV");
```

should be changed to:

```
string pathToLocalFile = @"C:\Report\WhateverTheFileNameYouWant.csv";
// or later as `string pathToLocalFile = @"C:\Report\" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".csv";`
client.DownloadFile("http://localhost:2114/File/DownloadCSV", pathToLocalFile);
```

Comment: Haha nice one, but the string result should be removed since DownloadFile is a void type. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing, is it possible I get the file name straight away from mvc controller?

Comment: Nope. I want to pass the remark value in controller to the console application. Is there a way to do it? How about JSON?

Comment: Ok I will do that.